# How to assign a string value to a particular row and column in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have created an empty metrics in python say

```
metric = np.empty([1,6])
```

Now, I am inserting some values to its particular row and column as shown below

```
metric[0:1,1:2] = 1.23
metric[0:1,2:3] = 2.4
metric[0:1,3:4] = 20
metric[0:1,4:5] = 10
metric[0:1,5:6] = 0.56
metric[0:1,6:7] = 0.50
```

Now, apart from the integer value, I want to insert a string to the 6th column of 1st row. i.e.

```
metric[0:1,6:7] = str('5') + "Days"
```

which I want to insert "5 Days" in the 6th column of 1st row.
How to do this??
please suggest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of dtype, default dtype for np array is float. you need to set it to object.

```
import numpy as np

metric = np.empty([1, 7], dtype=object)

metric[0,1] = 1.23
metric[0,2] = 2.4
metric[0,3] = 20
metric[0,4] = 10
metric[0,5] = 0.56
metric[0,6] = 'Days 0.50'

print(metric)
```

Comment: Thankyou. Do you have any idea about One dimensional CNN??

Comment: I know what is 1d cnn, but can you explain what you are trying to do, so I can help you better.

Comment: I have a question regarding 1d CNN. the default structure of 1d CNN contains 1 fully connected dense layer after after flatten layer. So, if i add more dense layers before the output dense layer of 1d CNN, can i call it a hybrid of Conv1d and MLP?

Comment: I do not think it will be called hybrid of 1d cnn and MLP. It will be called cnn network only.

Comment: But nowhere I have seen more than 1 fully connected dense layer in CNN network.